# Updating a list in React.js based on whether a new element was added or existing was edited

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `App` as my main component and `TodoList` to render my list of todos. When `Add Task` button is clicked, it opens an `input` which autosaves the input that we type. This is saved in a state `addTaskInput` which is then passed to `TodoList` component as a prop `addItem` *when the focus on input is removed*.

Now, we may edit the same element by simply clicking on it and typing. In that case, I want to update the same component. But if a new item is added, I want to add a new item to list.

1) How to check this?
2) I want to update my `todo` state inside `TodoList` component when list updates. Where should I call `setState` for that?

```js
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    showInput: false,
    addTaskInput: '',
    addItem:''
  }

  showAddTask = (e) => {
    this.setState({showInput: true})
  }

  saveInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({addTaskInput: e.target.value})
  }

  populateTaskList = (e) => {
    this.setState({addItem: e.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    const {showInput, addTaskInput, addItem} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Button
          message="Add Task"
          bsStyle="primary"
          onClick={this.showAddTask}
        />
        { showInput && <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add Task here..."
          value={addTaskInput}
          onChange={this.saveInput}
          onBlur={this.populateTaskList}
        /> }
        <TodoList
          addItem={addItem}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class TodoList extends Component {

  state = {
    todoList: ['a','aaa'],
    todo: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const {todo, todoList} = this.state;
    todoList.map((val) => {
      this.state.todo.push(<div key={val}>{val}</div>)
    })
    this.setState({todo});
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    return{
      ...prevState,
      ...nextProps
    }
  }

  render () {
    const {addItem, todoList, todo} = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        {todo}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the todoList in your app Component and pass that variable to the TodoList component:

```
class TodoList extends Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
    return{
      ...prevState,
      ...nextProps
    }
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <div> 
        {this.props.todoList.map((val) => <div key={val}>{val}</div>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And your app Component

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    showInput: false,
    addTaskInput: '',
    addItem:'',
    todoList: [],
  }

  showAddTask = (e) => {
    this.setState({showInput: true})
  }

  saveInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({addTaskInput: e.target.value})
  }

  populateTaskList = (e) => {
    const actualList = this.state.todoList;
    actualList.push(e.target.value);
    this.setState({addItem: e.target.value, todoList:actualList })
  }

  render() {
    const {showInput, addTaskInput, addItem, todoList} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Button
          message="Add Task"
          bsStyle="primary"
          onClick={this.showAddTask}
        />
        { showInput && <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add Task here..."
          value={addTaskInput}
          onChange={this.saveInput}
          onBlur={this.populateTaskList}
        /> }
        <TodoList
          todoList={todoList}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The only way I see is you maintain a key or index for each item only then you could update existing item. There is no way for you to know if the item is new or existing based on its value

2) To be able to update Todo's state you should give "addItem(item)" function on Todo which can be called with value that needs to be added/updated. And in that function you could update Todo's state. This function can be called from TodoList when text box loses focus or user stops typing.